# how to get the path in a dialog.selectedpath in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dialog

```
             Dim dialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
            dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
           Me.Label1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath = "C:\wamp\www"
           dialog.Description = "Select Application Configeration Files Path"
          ' If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
          '      apppath = dialog.SelectedPath
          '  End If
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(apppath & "\apppath.txt", apppath, False)



</i>
```

I just need to the path that had been selected in the code.. When viewing this into the label form it only print false!!

Comment: Dunno why Microsoft bother with the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), no-one ever reads it.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 Me.Label1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath = "C:\wamp\www"
```

means:

if `dialog.SelectedPath` is equal to `"c:\wamp\www"` then set the Label1.Text to True else set it to false.

What I suppose you want to do is

```
Dim dialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
dialog.SelectedPath = "C:\wamp\www"
dialog.Description = "Select Application Configeration Files Path"
If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    apppath = dialog.SelectedPath
    Me.Label1.Text = apppath
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(apppath & "\apppath.txt", apppath, False)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("No folder selected")
End If
```